# How would you access the Shape objects WITHIN a SmartArt object without getting Type Mismatch errors?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

**Question:** Is there any way to access Shape objects for each node inside of a SmartArt object? It seems like SmartArtNode objects have a [Shapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.smartartnode.shapes) property that could be used for this purpose, but I am getting Type mismatch errors when I try to send shapes from the SmartArtNode.Shapes to other subroutines.

**Background:** I am writing an iterator subroutine that takes in 2 parameters: a SmartArt object and a custom class object that has a method to perform actions on Shape objects. The subroutine is supposed to iterate over the Shape objects for each node inside the SmartArt, and call a method from the custom class object on each Shape.

Here is code for the iterator subroutine:

```
Public Sub IterateOverShapesInSmartArt(mySmartArt As SmartArt, manipulator As ShapeManipulator)
    Dim node As SmartArtNode
    Dim shpRange As ShapeRange
    For Each node In mySmartArt.AllNodes
        Set shpRange = node.Shapes
        If shpRange.count > 0 Then
            manipulator.ManipulateShape shpRange.Item(1)
        End If
    Next node
End Sub
```

For reference, the signature on the custom class (`ShapeManipulator`) method being called is as follows:

```
Public Sub ManipulateShape(myShape As Shape)
```

**Specific Problem:** When I try running this code, I get a **Run-time error '13': Type mismatch** triggered by the line `Set shpRange = node.Shapes`. Actually, I originally tried forgoing assignment of `node.Shapes` to a temporary variable and using the method call `manipulator.ManipulateShape node.Shapes(1)` instead, but then that method call produced the same Type mismatch error. I've also tried using a `For` loop with counter variables instead of `For Each` loop only to get the same error message. What is going on? When I debug, the Locals window shows the right types that match my declarations, so I am at a loss.

Comment: Kind of a side note... but the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.smartartnode.shapes) aren't very helpful either (surprise)... "To find the range, use the Count property" doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: @BigBen Yeah, the docs are pretty vague. Usually I take a look at the docs to get an idea of the object model, then poke around in the Immediate window to get an understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and I can confirm that `Set shpRange = node.Shapes` causes a type mismatch error.

I noticed, though, if shpRange is declared as a generic object instead (ie `Dim shpRange as Object`), it gets resolved to a ShapeRange, and there's no error.

In any case, you can avoid the assignment as follows...

```
Public Sub IterateOverShapesInSmartArt(mySmartArt As SmartArt, manipulator As ShapeManipulator)
    Dim node As SmartArtNode
    For Each node In mySmartArt.AllNodes
        With node
            If .Shapes.Count > 0 Then
                manipulator.ManipulateShape .Shapes.Item(1)
            End If
        End With
    Next node
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the code you suggested, but it results in the same type mismatch error on the call to ```manipulator.ManipulateShape```.

Comment: @B.Baker - what does `manipulator.ManipulateShape` do? Presumably you should pass it an `Object` instead of a `Shape`.

Comment: As per BigBen, `Public Sub ManipulateShape(myShape As Object)`.

Comment: @BigBen @Domenic ```ShapeManipulator``` is actually just an interface/prototype class, so they behavior of ```manipulator.ManipulateShape``` is different for each implementation of ShapeManipulator. (I did this because I have a bunch of features that perform actions on every shape inside a presentation or inside a selection, and i wanted to maintain one set of code to walk through the presentation/selection and to make development of new features faster.) I guess the only downside of changing the declaration from ```as Shape``` to ```as Object``` is losing Intellisense. Anyway, thanks guys.